# Como encontrar días de diferencia en fechas usando TimeStamp en Java?

Tags: java, sql, date, datetime, timestamp

Quisiera saber, cómo encontrar días de diferencia entre dos fechas en Java? Las fechas se encuentran en `TimeStamp`, luego, el formato es `2018-05-15 21:08:55.832`.

Comment: ¿que has intentado? ¿que tipo de dato utilizas para representar dichos timestamps?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer este artículo: [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes aclarar es, como te están preguntado, en qué tipo de atributo estás guardando esos timestamp. Supongo que los estarás recuperando de una BD, pero podría ser que los recuperes como long, como java.sql.Date, java.util.Date o, incluso, que sean simples Strings.

Aún y así, al final el proceso acaba siendo el mismo, ya que la forma correcta de resolver tu pregunta es mediante el uso de java.time.LocalDateTime (existente desde Java 8)

**Si el timestamp lo recibes como String**

```
String str = "2018-05-14 21:08:55.832";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

**Si el tiemstamp lo tienes como long**

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(t), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

**Si lo tuvieses como java.util.Date**

```
Date d = new Date();
LocalDateTime dateTime = d.toInstant()
              .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
              .toLocalDateTime();
```

A partir de ahí, el código siempre será el mismo:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Duration d = Duration.between(dateTime, now);
System.out.println("Dias diferencia entre fechas: " + d.toDays());
System.out.println("Horas diferencia entre fechas: " + d.toHours());
```

Espero que te sirva